# Thrust: inplace exclusive_scan of one member

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a vector of `MyElement`, which is defined as follows:

```
struct MyElement {
    int count;
    int prefixSum;
}
```

I would like to perform an in-place exclusive_scan of `count` but using `prefixSum` as the result, without changing `count`. Is that possible using thrust?

As an example, for the following input (`prefixSum` is initialized with zeros):

`{ (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0) }`

the correct output is:

`{ (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (0, 5), (1, 5) }`

namely `count` unchanged and `prefixSum` containing the exclusive prefix-sum of `count`.

This is what I've tried so far with thrust:

```
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct MyElement {
    int count;
    int prefixSum;

    // Needed by thrust
    __host__ __device__ MyElement() {
        count = 0;
        prefixSum = 0;
    }

    __host__ __device__ MyElement(int a) {
        count = 0;
        prefixSum = 0;
    }

    // Used for initialization
    __host__ MyElement(int count, int prefixSum) {
        this->count = count;
        this->prefixSum = prefixSum;
    }

    __host__ __device__ friend MyElement operator +(const MyElement& a, const MyElement& b) {
        return MyElement(0, a.count + b.count + a.prefixSum + b.prefixSum);
    }

    //__host__ __device__ MyElement& operator=(const MyElement& other) {
    //    // check for self-assignment
    //    if (&other == this) {
    //        return *this;
    //    }

    //    count = other.count;
    //    prefixSum = other.prefixSum;
    //    return *this;
    //}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    thrust::device_vector<MyElement> d_vector;
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(2, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));

    thrust::exclusive_scan(d_vector.data(), d_vector.data() + 10, d_vector.data());
    
    // Copy vector from device to host
    thrust::host_vector<MyElement> h_vector = d_vector;

    // Print
    for (const MyElement& element : h_vector) {
        printf("{ %d, %d }\n", element.count, element.prefixSum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the above code, the correct value for `prefixSum` is computed, however `count` is lost (set to zero). I've tried many variations of the sum and assignment operators, but I couldn't find a correct solution.

Comment: What do you imagine `MyElement(0, a.count + b.count + a.prefixSum + b.prefixSum)` will do except zero the count?

Comment: As I said I tried many variations of the sum and even the assignment operator. Using `MyElement(a.count, ...)` or `MyElement(b.count, ...)` doesn't yield the correct result.

Comment: The code I've posted is the closest output I can get so far.

Comment: It isn't obvious what you think the result should be. What should the result of A+B equal if A and B are MyElement? A.count or B.count? In-place doesn't mean what you think it does, as far as I can tell

Comment: This is difficult for at least 2 reasons.  1. Thrust seems to have a "missing" piece of functionality (being able to create a `transform_iterator` that returns a proper reference).  2.  You are making the problem hard by using an AoS data representation scheme.  Switching to a SoA storage model would make this problem fairly simple.

Comment: `MyElement` is actually part of a bigger SoA model, however since in my kernels I always need to access both `count` and `prefixSum`, I decided to group them together in order to save some global memory accesses.

Comment: I'm not sure how grouping them together saves some global memory accesses.  But I would point out that where data is "needed together" like this, thrust provides `zip_iterator` to do efficient on-the-fly conversion from SoA to AoS usage model.

Comment: If I have a `struct { int *counts; int *prefixSums }` my (other) kernels should do `myData.counts[thid]` and `myData.prefixSums[thid]`, e.g. two accesses. If instead I have `MyElement *myData` I can fetch just `myData[thid]`. Isn't that a single access vs two?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with a similar solution. A [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199750/thrust-scan-of-just-one-class-member) describes how one can perform an inclusive prefix sum on just one class member.

Since I can't perform a scan on one member and "output" it on another member, instead of initializing `prefixSum` to zero, I use the same value as `count` (I do this in a previous kernel, without using thrust).
Hence my new input becomes:

`{ (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1) }`

After that, I use thrust to perform an inclusive prefix sum on `prefixSum` only, getting:

`{ (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 4), (0, 4), (1, 5), (0, 5), (1, 6) }`

I actually need an exclusive prefix sum, however since I have the original `count`, the value I want is simply
`prefixSum - count`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach.  It's probably somewhat ugly that we are reinterpreting the array of structures as an array of integers.

The basic idea is to copy the data to be prefix-summed to the desired locations, shifted by 1, and then perform an *inclusive* scan there.

```
$ cat t13.cu
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

struct MyElement {
    int count;
    int prefixSum;

    // Used for initialization
    __host__ __device__ MyElement(int count, int prefixSum) {
        this->count = count;
        this->prefixSum = prefixSum;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    thrust::device_vector<MyElement> d_vector;
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(2, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(0, 0));
    d_vector.push_back(MyElement(1, 0));

    thrust::device_ptr<int> dvec(reinterpret_cast<int *>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vector.data())));
    auto pi_count = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dvec, thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1*2));
    auto pi_prefix = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dvec, thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), (_1*2)+1));

    thrust::copy_n(pi_count, d_vector.size()-1, pi_prefix+1);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(pi_prefix+1, pi_prefix + d_vector.size(), pi_prefix+1);

    // Copy vector from device to host
    thrust::host_vector<MyElement> h_vector = d_vector;

    // Print
    for (const MyElement& element : h_vector) {
        printf("{ %d, %d }\n", element.count, element.prefixSum);
    }

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t13 t13.cu -std=c++11
$ cuda-memcheck ./t13
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
{ 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0 }
{ 1, 0 }
{ 2, 1 }
{ 0, 3 }
{ 1, 3 }
{ 0, 4 }
{ 1, 4 }
{ 0, 5 }
{ 1, 5 }
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```